# How to connect to MS SQL Server using windows authentication of another user with nodeJS mssql

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I'm using the below code with nodeJS npm mssql 8.1.2 but I get

> The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows
> authentication. SSPI Handshake failed. Error while establishing a
> connection with Integrated security.

```
const sql = require('mssql');

let connectionstring = {
     domain: 'abc',
     driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
     server: server,
     user: username,
     password: password,
     database: database,
     options: {
         trustedconnection: true,
         enablearithabort: true,        
         encrypt: true            
     }
 };
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Why are you trying to do that at all? The whole point of using Windows Authentication is to connect using the current user's credentials instead of specifying them explicitly, and risk leaking them. Instead of trying to specify the Windows account in the connection string, add the account running your Node service as a login to SQL Server and give it just enough permissions to do its job

Comment: Is Node running on a non-domain computer? Windows Authentication can't work then. You'll have to add the machine to the same domain as the database server and use a domain account to run the Node service.

Comment: Yes, You're correct. But I wish to use other account in same domain and wish to inject credentials. Is there a way for it.

Answer (score 1):

Most drivers can't use Windows Auth with provided credentials; they support Windows Auth only by using the identity of the current process, or an identity provided by injecting credentials into the Windows Credential store, or injected into the process using `runas /netonly`.